# Locating map of Campament, Paterna, near Valencia Spain from 1950s

Tags: spain, 1950s, maps

I am trying to locate an older map of Campamento, Paterna, Valencia Spain.

I can find the current streets etc. easily enough using Google Maps, including Street View but my mother would like to see maps from back in the 1940s or 1950s because the streets were a little different back then.

Is there any way to obtain these older maps?

Answer (score 5):

This page of the Paterna city council shows different maps of the city, including orthoimages of the flight made by the Army Map Service of the United States in 1956 (under Cartografía --> Histórico --> Americano 1956):
[Geoportal Paterna](http://www.paterna.es:88/web/gtecnico/normativa/paterna/GeoPortal%20GIS%20PATERNA%20JS/Geoportal%20Paterna.html)

You can also check the [Centro Nacional de Información Geográfica](http://centrodedescargas.cnig.es/CentroDescargas/index.jsp#) web page. You can find old maps going to *Documentación geográfica y cartografía antiguas* --> *Planos de población* --> *Por mapa* --> *Selección de capas* --> *Minutas MTN50*  or *Ortofotos históricas - Americano B*

Answer (score 2):

For questions of "where do I locate X type of resource?" I like to use the [FamilySearch Wiki](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Main_Page). On the main page of the Wiki, you can use the map to identify a place to research, or you can use the search box to locate a place or topic.

The page for [Valencia, Spain](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Valencia,_Spain_Genealogy) describes how and where to find civil and church records.

A sidebar on the Valencia page leads to a page of links to online [maps of Spain](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Spain_Maps). Some of these are current (e.g. Google Maps), but many of the others are historical. The links are prepopulated to search for "Spain," but once you get to each site, you can search more specifically for "Valencia Spain" or maybe even "Paterna".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried earlier this morning to use of of the "apps" that the page you linked to suggested but unfortunately all of the historical maps were not detailed enough for street level. But thank you for this valuable research information!